# unable to send image from my application to mvc web api

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, retrofit2

I created an android app where i will catch or upload image from gallery and  sent it to my created web api and there i will save the image to database ,But  I am facing a lot of issues and cant find any solution whether my fault is in the android app sending method or receiving in API .what I tried

1.first I tried to send image as **base64 string** from my app but it shows an error while converting to **byte[]array** in my web api.
2.I tried to send the image as **byte[]array** but not working in API

So what I need i will send an image file from my android app and  save that image as byte in my database .

What I'v tried

```
            //Android App Code To Convert Image //

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            final byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, 
            Base64.DEFAULT);


              /*WEB API CODE*/

          [HttpPost]
          public Result PostDescription(string imageString )
          {
             var result = new Result();
             var a = file.Replace(" ", "+");
             try
                {
               using (var bmEntity = new Entity())
                {
                var img = new Model();
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(imageString );
                bmEntity.BrandingIssues.Add(img);
                result.success = bmEntity.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception erException)
        {

            result.success=0;


        }

        return result;
    }
```

All I want to send and image to my API and process that image to save in database.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your Android App Code, but if your input is truly base64 in your web api, the following should work:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
```

From here, you simply need to save it in your database.

If this doesn't work, I'm guessing your input in your PostDescription method isn't truly base64, but you could use a breakpoint to check whether it is or not.

If you need further help, it might be an idea to post the exception your api throws when trying to convert to byte[]